# Slingshot crashes when I type to search

Tags: wingpanel, slingshot, crash

This question has been asked before, but went unanswered once, and was closed once for being apparently off-topic. So opening this again.

I installed alacarte and deleted a duplicate entry for Xtreme Download Manager. Since then, the launcher crashes and restarts when I type to search an app.

Any way to undo this change? I tried reinstalling wingpanel but didn't seem to help.

Any way I can gather logs and post here for help?

Thanks!